# Are there any decent css template generators?

Tags: python, css, django

I am developing a small website using python. With a lot of decent libraries around in python I can't help but feel very inefficient when experementing with the styling (especially for positioning/layout).
Are there any decent css template generators(if possible using python)? From there on you could make slight adjustments in your css code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not python (Why would you want a lib, anyway?), but - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Thnx. Is there only one such generator? I'm surprised I didn't read about this before.

Answer (score 1):

There is also django-crispy-forms. http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/

You might be better off just starting with a pre-built CSS framework.

CSS Frameworks
http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/news/resources-cat/C56/ 
http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

CSS Form Framework
http://www.formee.org/ and http://formee.org/demo/index.htm 
http://www.jformer.com/

I wish there was a CSS generation component built into markup.py: http://markup.sourceforge.net/